# Is it possible to install a Debian testing (buster) kernel on Debian oldstable (jessie)?

Tags: debian, kernel, linux-kernel, package-management

Is it possible? I only want a few selected packages like the kernel (for hardware support), and leave everything else as-is on jessie. How can it be done? Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

You can download Buster [`linux-image` package from Debian repository](https://packages.debian.org/buster/linux-image-4.15.0-2-amd64) (it contains kernel, kernel modules and installation scripts in `post-inst`). I've just tested this scenario but for Stretch (kernel was 4.9.0-5, now it's 4.15.0-2) and VM successfully loaded.

**UPD**

Also I forget to add that you can install new kernel package from [backports Jessie repository](https://packages.debian.org/ru/jessie-backports/linux-image-4.9.0-0.bpo.5-amd64) directly or add to `/etc/apt/sources.list` next strings and download new kernel package as ordinary via `apt-get`:

```
# Backports repository
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian jessie-backports main contrib non-free
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian jessie-backports-sloppy main contrib non-free
```

If package from backports is enough for you, then it's the best approach then Buster package.

Comment: Yes, I mean "they're built to be tested". I did grammar mistakes. Sorry for my English, I'm not native speaker.

Comment: Thanks for detailed explanation! Now, I completely understand Debian packets flow. I remove first sentence in my answer to exclude confusing for others. It's not correctly formed.

Answer (score 1):

Debian is well-known for its flexible package combinations. You would have no problem running a Kernel from buster on jessie.

Here are the steps that ensures you to only get necessary packages from buster, and keep everything else as-is.

### 1. Add buster source

Add buster source to your apt sources so that apt can fetch packages from a later release version.

Open `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/buster.list` and add the source accordingly, components and mirrors of your choice.

```
# Buster repository
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian buster main
```

### 2. Add apt preference

Add apt preference file to ensure only essential packages are picked during installation.

Open `/etc/apt/preferences.d/buster.pref` and add the preferences.

```
Package: *
Pin: release n=buster
Pin-Priority: 50

Package: linux-image-* grub* firmware-*
Pin: release n=stretch
Pin-Priority: 500
```

A priority of 50 will ensure its packages won't be pulled automatically unless it's required to resolve dependencies.

Note: grub does not have to be upgraded, but jessie came with 2.02~beta2 while buster comes with 2.02 GA, so why not.

### 3. Upgrade kernel and grub

```
apt-get install linux-image-amd64 grub-pc
reboot
```

After rebooting, you should find the new kernel running.

```
# uname -a
Linux pony 4.18.0-2-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.18.10-2 (2018-11-02) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

---

The method above has been verified on both stretch-kernel-over-jessie and buster-kernel-over-jessie.